# Unity2D: Player continues to move after he respawns

Tags: unity-game-engine

Okay to be basic, I have a 2d top down click to move game with a small problem. You see I created my player to have three heart lives and that after you get hit by an object you lose a heart, once you lose a heart the player automatically re-spawn back to where he started. however I'm having problems with player's movement, as mentioned before to move my player you have to click around (click to move). When I click to a place and I get hit by an object my player does go back to where it started off at (which is what I want) but after it reset back to where it was in the beginning, my player would continue to move until it get to the destination (which is not want I want)

**This is my player movement's script:**

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

private Animator anim;
public float speed = 15f;
private Vector3 target;
public PlayerMovement playerMovementRef;
private bool touched;

void Start () {
    target = transform.position;
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}


void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePosition.z = 10; // distance from the camera
        target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
        target.z = transform.position.z;
    }

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    var movementDirection = (target - transform.position).normalized;

    if (movementDirection.x != 0 || movementDirection.y != 0) {
        anim.SetBool ("walking", false);
        anim.SetFloat("SpeedX", movementDirection.x);
        anim.SetFloat("SpeedY", movementDirection.y);
        anim.SetBool ("walking", true);
    }
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    float LastInputX = transform.position.x - target.x;
    float LastInputY = transform.position.y - target.y;


    if (touched) {
        if (LastInputX != 0 || LastInputY != 0) {
            anim.SetBool ("walking", true);
            if (LastInputX < 0) {
                anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", 1f);
            } else if (LastInputX > 0) {
                anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", -1f);
            } else {
                anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", 0f);
            }
            if (LastInputY > 0) {
                anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveY", 1f);
            } else if (LastInputY < 0) {
                anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveY", -1f);
            } else {
                anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveY", 0f);
            }
        }
    }else{
        touched = false;
        anim.SetBool ("walking", false);            
        }
    }
}
```

**And this is my Player's health script (this script respawns my player back to where it started after he is hit by an object):**

```
public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour {

//Stats
public int curHealth;
public int maxHealth = 3;
Vector3 startPosition;


void Start ()
{
    curHealth = maxHealth;
    startPosition = transform.position;
}


void Update ()
{

    if (curHealth > maxHealth) {
        curHealth = maxHealth;
    }
    if (curHealth <= 0) {

        Die ();
    }
}

void Die ()
{
    //Restart
    Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);


}


public void Damage(int dmg)
{
    curHealth -= dmg;
    Reset();
}


void Reset()
{
    transform.position = startPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that you already got a working answer but in future it may create more problems when you have to extend implementation of player.if you are NOT beginner with programming I have a better solution which requires a bit of programming. Would you want me to post an answer?

Comment: um okay sure thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you first click a location that the player walk towards,
`Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)` is true, so inside of the `if` statement you set mousePosition with the following line:

```
Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
```

and then you set the target equal to that with

```
target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
```

The problem is that outside of the if statement, but within the update method, you have

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Where the player's postition is continually changed to move towards the target. This is causing the problem because update() is constantly being called, even after you respawn, and if you don't assign the target a different value, your player will still move towards target, which was set before the player dies.

So put simply, target is only set once when you click a place to move, but your character always moves towards target, even after he respawns. Inside of the `Start()` method, write something like `PlayerMovement.target = startPosition`

Keep in mind target will either have to be public or have a public getter and setter in order to be able to access it from your health class.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried what you said where I should set target to equal startPostion but it's still doing the same thing. Also I do not know what you mean by resetting target.z or transform.postion. Thank you

Comment: @JesscaStone, see my edited post for a more detailed answer

Comment: @Veerbal Kint, I looked and tried out what you have said, I understand what you mean, however I got and error now regarding my playerhealth script. I made sure that the "target" from my playermovement was set to public but I still on an error. Thank you for replying if you can continue helping that would be amazing. Thank you

Comment: My error: An object reference is required to access non-static member `PlayerMovement.target'

Comment: Hey @JesscaStone, sorry for the late reply. The static keyword means you don't have to instantiate a new object. Without getting into object-oriented programming too much, just make target public:
public static Vector3 target; instead of private Vector3 target;

Comment: Also, since you found my post helpful, it would be great if you checked it as an answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't think that your method is working, I took the liberaty to film and upload to youtube to show you what is happening now with what I have add to my PlayerHealth script (I added the things you suggested). Thank you for all your help, I very much appreciate it, I would really be happy if you continued to help. This is the video: https://youtu.be/B_G5xfq3bf0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118129/discussion-between-jessca-stone-and-verbal-kint).